# Does my puppy have the hiccups?

Tags: dogs, health

I was worried  when my puppy started to have these strange shaky movements, as shown in this [video](http://youtu.be/33r78NZ6zL8).

It seems to have stopped at this point.

Does he just have the hiccups? Is this usual for dogs or puppies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I want to start this out by saying I am not a vet, and if you are worried you should consult an expert.

From my experience that does seem to just be a case of the hiccups.  It is common in puppies to experience hiccups, and they usually stop getting them around 6 months of age.

If you would like some more info check out [this page](http://www.petsadviser.com/pet-health/why-do-puppies-get-hiccups/), it has additional videos of puppies that have the hiccups.

Comment: I checked the videos, that was exactly what was happening. It didn't happen again and he's very fine and has been checked by the vet when he has his last shot of the year.